# Usage de « chicaya »

Tags: usage, étymologie, emprunts

Le *Canard* de ce matin emploie le mot « chicaya », que je ne connaissais pas mais dont le sens pouvait se deviner à partir du contexte :

> Pour tenter de ramener Jean-Pierre Raffarin à de meilleurs sentiments à son endroit après la ***chicaya*** qui les a opposés au sujet de l'augmentation de la TVA sur les billets d'entrée des parcs d'attractions, […]

Arrivé à ma destination, je consulte wiktionary qui confirme :

> **[chicaya](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chicaya)**: Querelle.
>   Vient de l’arabe شكاية qui signifie « plainte ».

Mais le TLFi ne connait pas ce mot, et un [Google ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=chicaya&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=7&smoothing=3) ne montre pas d'usage.

Ce mot est-il employé couramment, ou bien fait-il partie d'un argot spécifique ? À quelle période s'est fait son introduction dans la langue ? Et, puisqu'il vient de l'arabe, a-t-il été amené par une population particulière (pieds noirs, par exemple) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C'est la première fois que je lis ce mot. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu non plus. Au cas où il s'agirait d'un régionalisme, j'habite en France, dans la région de Paris.

Maintenant, en consultant ce [petit glossaire du pataouète](http://birkadem.free.fr/glossaireGLavallee.pdf), le pataouète étant un dialecte informel pied-noir<sup>(*)</sup>, je trouve effectivement *chicaya*: il s'agit d'une *chicane*, d'une *petite dispute*.

<sup>(*) Et que cette page (lien supprimé, la page ayant été hackée) décrit comme étant un "mélange de Français, d'Arabe, de Catalan, de Castillan, d'Italien et de Maltais".</sup>

Comment: Pas plus d'usage autour de moi.

Comment: Bref, son emploi dans un journal semble relever plus du snobisme que du style...

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est moins du snobisme que du journalisme francilien. Les pieds noirs ayant trouvé beaucoup d'emplois à la télévision, dans les média et aussi du coté de la rue d'Aboukir lorsqu'ils sont rentrés en France, ils y ont aussi apporté leurs tournures, leur humour et nombre d'expression 'du pays'. En Île-de-France ce mot est connu, car il a été aussi implanté par les immigrés du Maghreb, à Marseille il sera compris par tout le monde.

Answer (score 2):

**Chicaya** vient de l'arabe classique.

Mot très usité dans le monde arabophone, il signifie *plainte, réclamation, lamentation ...*

Answer (score 1):

**Des *chicayas* (au pluriel) est d'emploi très courant**, dans toute la France, aussi bien en région parisienne qu'ailleurs, et signifie: (petites) disputes, chamailleries, tergiversations, embrouilles, **chicaneries** (proximité sonore). **Son emploi n'est pas connoté** (j'apprends dans les autres réponses et commentaires son origine), ni spécialement journalistique.

Le style est légèrement familier.

Le *Canard Enchaîné*, journal satirique, au milieu de faits journalistiques très étayés, et qui relèvent pour beaucoup du journalisme d'investigation ou de l'actualité politique (assez parisienne), fait un usage permanent de tournures humoristiques, **de ce type de mots**, et de jeux de mots subtils ou faciles, du type de ceux de l'Almanach Vermot: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almanach_Vermot.

Il est d'ailleurs à l'origine de certaines expressions, qui sont rentrées par la suite dans l'usage courant et les dictionnaires. (blablater de mémoire pour n'en citer qu'un).

**Une *chicaya***: je ne pense pas avoir déjà entendu cette forme au singulier (le régionalisme est peut-être là).

**Autre mot similaire** dans le style et le sens: *pataquès* (masculin singulier).