# Chicailler ou chicayer ?

Tags: orthographe, régionalismes

En Normandie on disait autrefois "chicailler" pour se disputer (pas trop gravement), un peu comme pinailler.
Mais depuis peu les média(s) utilisent "des chicayas".
Quelle est l'orthographe recommandée : "chicailler" ou "chicayer" ?

Answer (score 1):

Il ne s'agit pas du même mot ou verbe, la similitude est accidentelle.

*[Chicaya](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/usage-de-chicaya)* vient de l'arabe [شكاية qui signifie « plainte, lamentation »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chicaya).

*[Chicailler](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chicailler)* vient du normand. Il est peut-être apparenté avec chicaner.